# Unable to catch error from nodejs/ mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, try-catch

I am attempting to rethrow and subsequently catch an error returned from a mongoose `findOne` statement.

When my player does not exist, I encounter the following error:

> events.js:188
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> Error: Unhandled "error" event. (player not found: NONEXISTENT_PLAYERNAME)
>       at Function.emit (events.js:186:19)
>       at model.Query. (/Users/blair/Documents/Lobster/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4083:13)
>       at /Users/blair/Documents/Lobster/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
>       at /Users/blair/Documents/Lobster/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)

My code:

**Game Route**

```
router.post('/update_player', (req, res) => {
    gameController.updatePlayer(req, res);
});
```

**Game Controller**

```
controller.updatePlayer = async (req, res) => {
    const { game_name, player_name, x, y, z } = req.body;
    Game.updatePlayer(game_name,player_name,x,y,z).then(updatedGame => {
        res.status(200).json(updatedGame);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
};
```

**Game Model**

```
GamesModel.updatePlayer = (gameName, playerName, x, y, z) => {
    return PlayersModel.findOne({name: playerName}, (err,player) => {
        if (!player) throw `player not found: ${playerName}`;
        if (err) throw err;
        return GamesModel.findOneAndUpdate({ name: gameName, 'players._id': player._id }, 
        { $set: { 'players.$' : { _id: player._id, x, y, z } } },
        {  
            projection: { players: { '$elemMatch': { _id: player._id} } },
            returnNewDocument: true
        },
        (err, game) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            return game;
        });
    });
};
```

I would like to return the correct error detail in my controller.

Comment: Can you add `console.log("Error=====", err)` in your model below `PlayersModel.findOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it easily by using **Callbacks**.

Ref:

- https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm

**Controller**

```
controller.updatePlayer = async (req, res) => {
    const { game_name, player_name, x, y, z } = req.body;
    Game.getPlayerDetails(playerName, function(err, playerData) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            Game.updateGame(game_name, playerData, function (err, updatedData) {
                if (err) {
                        res.status(500).send(err);
                } else {
                    res.status(200).send(updatedData)
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

**Model:**

```
GamesModel.getPlayerDetails = (playerName, callback) => {
    PlayersModel.findOne({name: playerName}, callback);
} 

 // You can put below code in respective models and import them in controller and use.

GamesModel.updateGame = (gameName, player) => {
    GamesModel.findOneAndUpdate({ name: gameName, 'players._id': player._id }, 
    { $set: { 'players.$' : { _id: player._id, x, y, z } } },
    {  
        projection: { players: { '$elemMatch': { _id: player._id} } },
        returnNewDocument: true
    }, callback);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. This did the trick with minor edits. Just added cb to updateDate and appended x,y,z to player.

Comment: Cool, hope it gave you idea!! Keep rocking!!